# Make class variable accessible as instance variable using metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

My goal is to make ExampleList behave like a list including class variable `a` of `Example` class should be accessible as instance variable as following:

```
ex = ExampleList([1, 2, 4])
ex.a
```

```
class MetaList(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = list.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj


class Example:
    a = 5


class ExampleList(Example, metaclass=MetaList):
    pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why use a metaclass here?

Comment: if you just define `class ExampleList(list, Example): pass` it will act as you require

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to involve a metaclass here. You can simply use inheritance, with `Example` acting as a mixin:

```
>>> class Example:
...     a = 5
...
>>> class ExampleList(list, Example):
...     pass
...
>>> mylist = ExampleList()
>>> mylist.extend(range(5))
>>> mylist
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> mylist.a
5
```